# How to find a SKDownload's transaction on the Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, in-app-purchase, storekit, skdownload

On iOS, `SKDownload` has

`@property(nonatomic, readonly) SKPaymentTransaction *transaction`

which conveniently allows to finish a Transaction whenever a hosted content has been downloaded.

On the Mac though, `SKDownload` doesn't have that, so I find myself having to browse the `SKPaymentQueue` and look for that transaction having that download.

Any of you doing so?

The problem is that sometimes I won't reach the "finishTransaction" code, but I don't really know how to finish that transaction otherwise! On iOS it's easy, since I just finish the transaction associated to the download.

To sum up, it would be great to know how to finish transactions with downloads on Mac. Does it happen implicitly?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Looks like transactions are finished automatically when all downloads are fetched?

Comment: "transactions are finished automatically when all downloads are fetched" — uh... no. I don't think so. Right now, I do what I said... I look in the SKPaymentQueue. I have a TSI opened with DTS about it, but since they haven't replied after 3 days, I'm concerned they themselves don't know ;-)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've noticed that special method was used in Apple's video, however I didn't find sources of Demo app (named Fruit Stand), so guess they were using something like you have suggested. Screenshot https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/193306240/finishTransaction.png Please, post an update in comments if you find some information

Comment: ah! That's a very good screenshot you got there! That `transactionForDownload:` probably does what I do though. Which Session is this? It's not in 305 in 2013, right? FYI: DTS is busy with my question. I guess/hope Apple hast that Fruit Stand app ;)

Comment: It is Session 302 from 2012, unfortunately they never show implementation of `transactionForDownload` on that recording :)